# Distribute a new RDD like an existing RDD in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have two RDDs with different keys:

```
RDD1: (K1, V1)
RDD2: (K2, V2)
```

And I have a function that operates on data from `V2` and that subsequently maps `K2` and `K1`. The result is a new RDD, `RDD3: (K1, V2_transformed)`. My end results are based on some operations on `RDD1`'s `V1` and `RDD3`'s `V2_transformed` *by key*.

It seems to me that it would be beneficial to have `RDD3` be distributed the same way as `RDD1`, to avoid a costly join afterwards. Is there a way to a priori specify that I want `RDD3` distributed the same as `RDD1`?

I work with PySpark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numpartitions))`, if you use the same partitioner for both RDD's you should be fine.

Comment: Since I use Python, can I still pass a partitioner to `rdd.partitionBy`? Is that the `portable_hash` that is mentioned in the docs (`partitionBy(self, numPartitions, partitionFunc=portable_hash)`)?

Comment: @Def_Os not sure never used the python version

Comment: `rdd.partitionBy` without arguments (choosing the default) works just fine for this.